# Real matrices with non-real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

[image]

I know this covers a lot, so perhaps someone could redirect me to a helpful website.

for a) I have no idea where to start on the proof, as I don't understand why this is true.

for b) I also have no idea.

for c) A is a real matrix, so if one eigenvalue is complex, the others are too? (the conjugate of the first)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for a): What does it mean for $z$ to be an eigenvector? It means that $Az=\lambda z$. When would you say that two complex quantities are equal? You equate some parts. What, with what?

Hint for b) Assume they are linearly dependent and $y=kx$ for some $k$. Then use (a) and the fact that $b \neq 0$.

Comment: $Ax=\lambda x$ => $ax1 +bix2$  and  $Az=\lambda z$ => $(a+bi)(x+iy)$ => $x(a-bi)-y(b-ai)$ so for them to be equal.... I don't understand.

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you have written here. But $Az=\lambda z$ means $A(x+iy)=(a+bi) (x+iy)$. If you expand and equate the real parts and the imaginary ones, you obtain the result.

Comment: I see what Az expands to, but not Ax or Ay since I dont know what x or y are.

Comment: Ok, let's expand. $A(x+iy)=Ax+iAy$. On the other hand, $(a+ib)(x+iy)=ax+ayi+bxi+i^2by=ax+i(ay+bx)-by$. So, do you see now that equating the real parts and the imaginary parts give us the result?

Comment: Ohhhh my goodness, I got that result but was thinking of the question in the completely wrong way (so I thought my result was incorrect). Yes, I now understand. Thank you so much for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Hints have already been given for (a), (b), so I'll address (c). There are definitely matrices with both real and non-real eigenvalues: as a trivial example, let $A$ have non-real eigenvalues, and be $n \times n$ and consider the block matrix:

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} k&  0 \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix}$$

where $k$ is real. This adds an eigenvector of the form $(1,0,...,0)^T$, with real eigenvalue $k$. On the other hand, for all eigenvectors $v$ of $A$, the vector $(0, v^T)^T$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with the same eigenvalue. However, you are right to note that if a real matrix has a non-real eigenvalue, then the conjugate is also an eigenvalue.  This is because the characteriztic polynomial of a real matrix has real coefficients, and real polynomials always have root sets symmetrix under conjugation.

Comment: Sooo why doesnt the span of {x,y} contain real eigenvectors of A? If A is nxn then it surely has other, real eigenvalues, therefore real eigenvectors.

Comment: Not necessarily. If $n$ is even, then the characteristic polynomial is of even degree and may well have no real roots (for example, if we could arrange that the characteristic polynomial is $x^n + 1$ for $n$ even, which we can do). If it is odd, then since odd polynomials have at least one real root...sure, it has to have one real eigenvalue (for intuition,most rotations of the plane has real eigenvalues, whereas rotations of 3-space must have a fixed axis)

Comment: So then wouldn't it have one real eigenvector, making the question invalid?

Comment: No. The span of $x,y$ is a two dimensional space, the other eigenvector can (and always will) fall outside of that space. Consider the matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$. The only real eigenvectors are $(k,0,0)^T$ for $k$ real non-zero, corresponding to eigenvalue 1. But the $x,y$ your question is asking out span the plane $(0, a,b)^T$.where $a,b$ vary over all reals.

Answer (score 0):

We are given that $A$ is a real $n \times n$ matrix with a complex eigenvalue $\lambda = a + bi$, $b \ne 0$, and a (necessarily) complex vector $\vec z \in \Bbb C^n$ such that

$A \vec z = \lambda \vec z. \tag{1}$

Writing

$\vec z = \vec x + i\vec y, \tag{2}$

with $\vec x, \vec y \in \Bbb R^n$, and inserting it into (1) yields

$A(\vec x + i\vec y) = \lambda(\vec x + i\vec y) = (a + ib)(\vec x + i\vec y). \tag{3}$

(3) may be written as

$A \vec x + iA \vec y = (a\vec x - b\vec y) + i(a \vec y + b \vec x), \tag{4}$

or, writing the real and imaginary parts out separately, we find

$A\vec x = a\vec x - b\vec y, \tag{5}$

$A\vec y = a\vec y + b\vec x. \tag{6}$

It should be remembered that though $A$ is a real matrix it must be construed as acting on the complex vector space $\Bbb C^n$; otherwise the assertion that $A$ has a complex eigenvalue makes no sense.  Thus we consider $A$ as as acting on $\Bbb C^n$; as such, it is a $\Bbb C$-linear map, that is, $A(c \vec z) = cA \vec z$ for any $\vec z \in \Bbb C^n$ and $c \in \Bbb C$; thus we justify writing $A(\vec x + i \vec y) =A\vec x + iA\vec y$ which was tacitly invoked in the transiton 'twixt (3) and (4).  In any event, the preceding establishes item (1).

We observe that $b \ne 0$ implies $\vec x \ne 0 \ne \vec y$; for if $\vec x = 0$, then by (5), $b\vec y = 0$ and hence, since $b \ne 0$, $\vec y = 0$.  Likewise if $\vec y = 0$, (6) forces $\vec x = 0$; this shows either both $\vec x$, $\vec y$ are zero or neither are; but both cannot be zero since the eigenvector $\vec z \ne 0$; thus $\vec x \ne 0 \ne \vec y$.

As for item (2), note that if $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb R$ (that is, as elements of $\Bbb R^n$), then there must exist nonzero $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$ with

$\alpha \vec x + \beta \vec y = 0, \tag{7}$

or

$\vec y = -\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} \vec x = k \vec x \tag{8}$

with $0 \ne k = -(\alpha/\beta) \in \Bbb R$.  But then, from (3),

$(1 + ik)A \vec x = A(\vec x  +i k \vec x) = A(\vec x + i \vec y) = (a + bi)(\vec x + i\vec y)$
$= (a + bi)(\vec x +i k\vec x) = (1 + ik)(a + bi)\vec x,  \tag{9a}$

or, cancelling out $1 + ik$,

$A\vec x = (a + bi)\vec x. \tag{9b}$

Now the left hand side of (9b) is real, since both $A$ and $\vec x$ are; but the right is only real in the event $b = 0$; thus the hypothesis $b \ne 0$ prohibits (7) and hence $\vec x$, $\vec y$ are linearly independent, establishing item (2).

As for (3), suppose that $\text{span}\{\vec x, \vec y \}$ contained a real eigenvector $\vec w$; then we would have

$\vec w = \alpha \vec x + \beta \vec y \tag{10}$

with $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$ not both zero.  Furthermore $\vec w$ being a real eigenvector satisfies

$A\vec w = \mu  \vec w \tag{11}$

with $\mu \in \Bbb R$ since $A$ and $\vec w$ are real.  Using (10) in (11) we have

$A(\alpha \vec x + \beta \vec y) = \mu (\alpha \vec x + \beta \vec y), \tag{12}$

or by virtue of (5)-(6),

$\alpha A \vec x + \beta A \vec y = \alpha(a \vec x - b \vec y) + \beta(a \vec y + b \vec x) = \mu \alpha \vec x + \mu \beta \vec y, \tag{13}$

and since $\vec x$, $\vec y$ are both non-vanishing and linearly independent we can collect and equate their coefficients in (13):

$a \alpha + b \beta = \mu \alpha, \tag{14}$

$-b \alpha + a \beta = \mu \beta; \tag{15}$

we see that these two equations are in fact the eigen-equation for a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} = \mu \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}, \tag{16}$

and recalling that $(\alpha, \beta)^T \ne 0$ we see that $\mu$ must be an eigenvalue of

$C = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}; \tag{17}$

but it is easily seen that the eigenvalues of $C$ are $a \pm bi$, since the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is $x^2 -2a x + (a^2 + b^2)$; since $b \ne 0$, $\mu$ cannot be real; we have reached a contradiction from which it follows that $\text{span}\{\vec x, \vec y \}$ contains no real eigenvector $\vec w$; thus is item (3) established.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***